# Keep running Python script when SSH closed

Tags: python, ssh

I'm connecting to my Rasbperry Pi with SSH and trying to run a python script that will keep running even if SSH connection is closed. I'm trying this command:

```
nohup python3 /scriptPATH.py &
```

I already gave permisions with

```
chmod +x /scriptPATH.py.py
```

And added to the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

All I get is this message, script isn't running while SSH active neither when closed:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

The error from nohup.out:

> File
> "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.   (unknown error:
> DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
> chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so
> ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

There seems to be a problem with Selenium, the script works fine when I run it from IDE or Jupyter Notebook

Thanks!!

Comment: maybe you mean `nohup python3 /scriptPATH.py &`, and you can also check what is in nohup.out.

Comment: True, added & and output info, thank you